# Parse: It's his job **to stand there.**

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

"It is his job **to stand there**"

What's the function of the infinitive phrase in this sentence? I'm leaning towards it being an appositive of the complement "his job" or of the subject "it", but I'm not certain.

Comment: This is a transform (by Extraposition) of the sentence _To stand there is his job_, in which the infinitive subject _(For him) to stand there_ is extraposed to the end of the sentence, leaving a dummy _it_ as the actual subject. This _it_ governs singular verb agreement, no matter what the original subject was, but since it is almost always a clause or phrase, this is seldom an issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. "It" = dummy pronoun
2. "is" = verb
3. "his" = possessive pronoun modifying "job"
4. "job" = subject complement
5. "to stand there" = subject phrase containing:

   - "to stand" infinitive used as noun
   - "there" = adverb modifying the infinitive